# Seleccionar un campo en múltiples tablas en MySQL

Tags: mysql

tengo una duda con respecto a una query en la que intento obtener un result-set que me muestre los siguientes datos:

```
COLUMNA1    COLUMNA2     COLUMNA3   
Cliente     Tienda       Tabla
```

Las 3 campos están relacionados de manera jerárquica, es decir, el `cliente` lo relaciono con el `id` de la `tienda`, y la `tienda` la relaciona con el `id` que tiene una tabla. El problema aquí es que yo quiero obtener un *result-set* para 16,000 tablas, pero no logro definir mi `INNER JOIN` para que automáticamente me relacione mis 16,000 tablas,

¿Alguien me podría dar una solución a esto?

Comment: Si necesitas relacionar con 90K tablas, me temo que no te queda de otra que escribir o generar un _query_ que incluya las 90,000 en la sentencia from. La verdad, desconozco si MySQL va a aceptar para procesar el texto de ese query, ya que va a _pesar_ algunos megas.

Comment: En realidad, lo primero que cuestionaría es ese modelo. ¿De verdad se necesitan 90,000 tablas?